# Batch Script - Writing all contents of Variable into a File

Tags: batch-file, automation

Loading contents of a variable into a text file.

```
Echo %var% > Temp.txt
```

The above code works fine,but in case there are two lines defined in the variable, it prints the first line in the terminal and prints the second line into the text file. 
Is there any way to write all the content of the variable to the text file ? 
For example:

var :

```
 123
 234
```

Only 234 is written into Temp.txt, but i want 123 & 234 written into Temp.txt, one below the other.

And, is there any way to load data into a Excel file from a batch script ? If so, would like some basic examples.

**EDIT :** 
This is how the variable`var` is defined:

```
FOR /F "Tokens=1*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKCU\....."') DO (
        IF NOT "!var!"=="" SET "var=!var! && Echo."
        SET "var=!var!%%A"
)
Echo %var% >> Temp.txt
```

Comment: How did you manage to get to lines in an environment variable? Can you show your assignment?

Comment: `var` wasnt the actual variable name, that i used to store the data lines. Didnt know that `var` was a environment variable like `%username%` and others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use

```
( echo %var% ) > temp
```

But your variable doesn't contains multiline text, it contains multiple `ECHO` instructions.

For real multiline text you need to use a linefeed character.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET LF=^


REM Two empty lines are required
set "var="
FOR /F "Tokens=1*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKCU\....."') DO (
        IF defined var SET "var=!var!!LF!"
        SET "var=!var!%%A"
)
Echo !var! >> Temp.txt
```

Comment: I was writting the EXACTLY the same code. +1 Faster than me :)

Comment: `Fools seldom differ`

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%A IN (123 234) DO (
        IF NOT "!var!"=="" SET "var=!var! && Echo."
        SET "var=!var!%%A"
)
ECHO %var%
echo========================
Echo %var% >> u:\Temp.txt
ECHO =======================
(Echo %var% )>> u:\Temp2.txt
ECHO =======================
SET var

GOTO :EOF
```

Perhaps this will clue you in on what's happening.

The solution is the `(Echo %var% )>> u:\Temp2.txt`

Where `>>` could be `>` to create anew rather than append.

`U:` is my RAMdrive

Answer (score 0):

Try this to write data into excel file

awk 'BEGIN{ OFS="|"; print "Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4|Column5|Column6"};
         NR > 1{print "IND", "INR", $6, $7, $8, $9;}' Inputdata.txt > Output.xls

Comment: Awk function isn't present in Bat/Batch scripting right ? It says Awk not recognized

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
>temp.txt echo !var!
endlocal
```

Special characters as line feeds or carriage returns included in variables need delayed expansion to be properly handled.

Comment: Actually, i had used `&& Echo.` in loop while defining the variable to create a line by line output. When i use your approch i get output like this :

`123 && Echo.234`

Comment: @Lastwish, sorry, i don't see what you are doing. I was thinking the variable contained the two values with a LF or CR between them but it seems this is not the case. Can you include in the question the code you are using to set the variable?

Comment: Added the snippet used for the definition of the variable `var`

Comment: @Lastwish, do you need the content into the variable or the only requirement it to get the data into the file?

Comment: would like to store the content into the variable first,... as there are other similar requirments which will need this same functionality,..